# Custom options not showing in frontend

Tags: magento-1.5.1

I am using Magento 1.5.1.0 and have several shops setup.

I am trying to add framing options to the existing products in two of my stores.  I have added this successfully in Domingo Direct, see http://www.domingodirect.co.uk/index.php/deep-thoughts-no-2.html

However in Hornchurch fine art the framing options do not appear, see http://www.hornchurchfineart.co.uk/index.php/moonlite-parliament-no-1.html

If you try to add this artwork to the cart I get the error "Please specify the product required option(s)." as expected.

Does anyone know why the options are not showing?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem with the custom option. Then i found out the solution after a long search in the database. You just forget to insert the values in **"catalog_product_entity_varchar"** table.
 For custom option we need to insert 4 records in the **"catalog_product_entity_varchar"** table.
 After inserting the table it works well.. Hope it will helps you..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do I need to add to this table.  I have had a look but can find no reference to the options that are working on Domingo site?